# How to model trees in Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a very large set of posts & comments, represented as a list of edges:

```
children_id, parent_id
```

This pairs are edges in various trees.

I want to find, for each children_id, the root post:

```
children_id, parent_id, root_id
```

How can I do that in Spark efficiently?

My guess is that I'd have to use a broadcast variable to share a lookup key among nodes.

Comment: What are these children_id and parent_id? Are they integers? How many of them you have?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you need to do.

If you *only* need to find the root post id, then using a broadcast variable to share a lookup seems totally fine.

If you need to do lots of tree (or more generally graph processing) then look at the new graphframe API.

https://databricks.com/blog/2016/03/03/introducing-graphframes.html

Comment: If that's possible to put everything into a map and broadcast that, then you don't need apache spark. You don't need anything. Just look it through in a few threads...